# How do i transfer output from one command to another command

Tags: sorting, join, awk, pipe

Here is my issue:

[image]

So pretty much i have this question to answer, as you can see i need to use to use the awk, sort, and join command, im able to get the format of the answers i want using commands:
`awk -F: '{printf "%-22s\n", $2 }' departments`
AND
`awk -F: '{printf "%-6s\t %-38s\t %-1s\n", $1 $2 $3 }'` courses.

I tried using the pipe command, and using a semi-colon to join the two but no luck, I'm stuck and I'm not sure what to do, I've been working on this problem for 9 hours now sadly, please help, you do not have to give me the direct answer but kind of point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post the code you actually tried, with the pipe, what the result was, and what you expected from it?

Comment: Better paste text, not image [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19648412/edit). Just indent it with 4 spaces. That's how [mardown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (ans so SO works).

Answer (score 0):

"|" pipe is what I would use.

See: http://computer-programming-forum.com/11-awk/36867b18c8ac7390.htm

Comment: tried but no luck with pipe, it simply only displays the second awk command

Answer (score 0):

In `gawk` there is an `asorti` function and you could do the whole thing in `gawk`. For instance:

```
gawk -F: -f genTab.awk departments courses
```

where `genTab.awk` is

```
NR==FNR {
    dep[$1]=$2;    next
}

{
    desc[$1]=$2;   cred[$1]=$3;  dep2[$1]=dep[$4]
}

END {
    nn = asorti(desc, ind)
    for (i=1; i<=nn; i++) {
       j=ind[i]
       printf "%-22s%-6s%-38s%s\n", dep2[j],j,desc[j],cred[j]
    }
}
```